# Extracting value from XMLType Column

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I was learning XMLType applications when I came accross the below problem. It's returning NULL insteade of the CD Title.  I am not sure why it's behaving in this way.

```
DROP TABLE  Xml_tab;
 /
 CREATE TABLE Xml_tab ( xmlval xmltype);
 /
INSERT INTO Xml_tab
VALUES(XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(
  '<CATALOG><CD><TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE><ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY><PRICE>10.90</PRICE><YEAR>1985</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE><ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1988</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE><ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1982</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE><ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY><PRICE>10.20</PRICE><YEAR>1990</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Eros</TITLE><ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST><COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY><COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1997</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>One night only</TITLE><ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY><PRICE>10.90</PRICE><YEAR>1998</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE><ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY><PRICE>8.10</PRICE><YEAR>1973</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE><ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY><PRICE>8.50</PRICE><YEAR>1990</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Romanza</TITLE><ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST><COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY><PRICE>10.80</PRICE><YEAR>1996</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE><ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY><PRICE>8.70</PRICE><YEAR>1987</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Black angel</TITLE><ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST><COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY><PRICE>10.90</PRICE><YEAR>1995</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE><ARTIST>Many</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY><PRICE>10.20</PRICE><YEAR>1999</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>For the good times</TITLE><ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY><PRICE>8.70</PRICE><YEAR>1995</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE><ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1997</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE><ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY><PRICE>8.20</PRICE><YEAR>1971</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE><ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST><COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY><COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY><PRICE>7.90</PRICE><YEAR>1996</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>The very best of</TITLE><ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Island</COMPANY><PRICE>8.90</PRICE><YEAR>1990</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Stop</TITLE><ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY><PRICE>8.90</PRICE><YEAR>1988</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE><ARTIST>T''Pau</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY><PRICE>7.90</PRICE><YEAR>1987</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE><ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY><PRICE>8.90</PRICE><YEAR>1983</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE><ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST><COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY><PRICE>7.80</PRICE><YEAR>1983</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE><ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY><PRICE>9.90</PRICE><YEAR>1991</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE><ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY><PRICE>7.90</PRICE><YEAR>1987</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Picture book</TITLE><ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST><COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY><COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY><PRICE>7.20</PRICE><YEAR>1985</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Red</TITLE><ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST><COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY><COMPANY>London</COMPANY><PRICE>7.80</PRICE><YEAR>1987</YEAR></CD><CD><TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE><ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY><PRICE>8.20</PRICE><YEAR>1987</YEAR></CD></CATALOG>'));
  /
  COMMIT;




 SELECT P.xmlval.extract('//CATALOG/CD/TITLE/text()').GETSTRINGVAL AS CD

FROM   Xml_tab P;
```

Any explanation is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit confusing but you can get cd titles like this:

```
SELECT extract(value(b),'//TITLE/text()').getstringval() AS CD
FROM   xml_tab x, 
       TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(extract(xmlval,'//CATALOG/CD'))) b
```

You sort of convert the xml into a table first and then get the values with the EXTRACT function.

Comment: thanks . I see you used "//TITLE/" instead of full path . can you please tell me what's the use of "//"

Comment: Quote from Oracle documentation: "//" is used to identify all descendants of the current node. For example, PO//ZIP matches any zip code element under the "PO" element.

Comment: thanks for explaining ! I have another question..  could you please tell me why below query is not working :( . it's probably very basic but if you could help me..

DECLARE
  l_xml xmltype;
BEGIN
  SELECT SYS_XMLAGG(xmlelement("emp",xmlforest(e.employee_id,e.first_name,e.last_name,e.salary)))
  INTO l_xml
  FROM employees e;
  SELECT extract(l_xml, '//employee_id/text()').getStringVal() AS empno,
    extract(l_xml, '//first_name/text()').getStringVal()      AS ename,
   
   
   
    extract(l_xml, '//salary/text()').getStringVal()        AS sal
  FROM dual;
END;
an INTO clause is expected

Comment: You're missing the INTO clause in the SELECT statement.